# Paypal return url with variable not working

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I want Paypal to auto-return to my "thank-you" page once the payment has been made. I managed to do it in sandbox and it worked without problems. Now that I have switched to 'live', I am not getting back the GET variables along with the return url **as I used to do in sandbox.**

Below is the full button link generated. It's working and does everything except passing back the transaction ID and the custom field back to my "return" url.

`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&no_shipping=1&lc=US&item_name={$itemName}&amount={$itemPrice}&business={$businessEmail}&custom={$custom}&amp;currency_code=USD&amp;notify_url={$notifyUrl}&return={$returnUrl}";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you got PDT configured on your sandbox account but forgot to do the same on your live account.

That said, what exactly are you trying to do with your return URL?  Are you updating databases, sending out email notifications, etc?  If so, you'll want to use IPN for that instead, which is very similar to PDT except that it happens apart from the checkout flow altogether.  PayPal POSTs the data to a listener script sitting on your server.

With PDT the user is never guaranteed to make it back to your return URL, even if Auto-Return is enabled.  They could simply close the browser before the redirect happens, for example.

IPN will be triggered every time a transaction occurs whether the user makes it back to your site or not.  This is the recommended way to automate post-order procedures.

Comment: remove space from your return url may be that's the issue